# Calculating cumulative standard deviation by group using R

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R and wanted to calculate the cumulative standard deviation by group in R. I have a data frame D which has an ID for visitor and the corresponding time on page (top) spent in each page as below

```
ID   top
v1   2.3  
v1   4.8
v1   10.2
v2   16.2
v2   12.2
v2   14.3
v2   12.4
v3   8.2
v3   8.8
```

The output needs to look like this

```
ID   top  cum_sd
v1   2.3  
v1   4.8   1.76
v1   10.2  4.03
v2   16.2
v2   12.2  2.82
v2   14.3  2.00
v2   12.4  1.15
v3   8.2   
v3   8.8   0.42
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `runSD` from `TTR`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we apply the `runSD` on the 'top' column and assign (`:=`) the output to create the 'cum_sd'.

```
library(data.table)
library(TTR)
setDT(df1)[, cum_sd := round(runSD(top, n=1, cumulative=TRUE),2) ,ID]
df1
#  ID  top cum_sd
#1: v1  2.3     NA
#2: v1  4.8   1.77
#3: v1 10.2   4.04
#4: v2 16.2     NA
#5: v2 12.2   2.83
#6: v2 14.3   2.00
#7: v2 12.4   1.87
#8: v3  8.2     NA
#9: v3  8.8   0.42
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with base functions:

```
cumsd <- function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x), head, x=x), sd)
df1$cum_sd <- ave(df1$top, df1$ID, FUN=cumsd)
```