# Cumulative pnorm in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking to calculate a cumulative `pnorm` through as series.

```
set.seed(10)
df = data.frame(sample = rnorm(10))
# head(df)
#   sample
# 1  0.01874617
# 2 -0.18425254
# 3 -1.37133055
# 4 -0.59916772
# 5  0.29454513
# 6  0.38979430
```

I would like the result to be

```
# na
# 0.2397501   # last value of pnorm(df$sample[1:2],mean(df$sample[1:2]),sd(df$sample[1:2]))
# 0.1262907   # last value of pnorm(df$sample[1:3],mean(df$sample[1:3]),sd(df$sample[1:3]))
# 0.4577793    # last value of pnorm(df$sample[1:4],mean(df$sample[1:4]),sd(df$sample[1:4]))
# .
# .
# .
```

if we can do this preferable in data.table, it would be nice.

Comment: Eventually you can do it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874582/calculating-cumulative-standard-deviation-by-group-using-r/34878700#34878700

Comment: I think you have a syntax error and this should be `pnorm(df$sample[1:2],mean(df$sample[1:2]),sd(df$sample[1:2]))` and etc. (you've combined mean and sd together).

Comment: Non-equi join: `df[, rid := .I][.(rid = rid), on=.(rid < rid), pnorm(sample[.N], mean(sample), sd(sample)), by=.EACHI]` This calculation seems weird / not useful, though. If you first calculate cumulative mean and sd cols, it can be a lot less inefficient, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
set.seed(10)
df = data.frame(sample = rnorm(10))

foo <- function(n, x) {
  if (n==1) return(NA)
  xn <- x[1:n]
  tail(pnorm(xn, mean(xn), sd(xn)), 1)
}

sapply(seq(nrow(df)), foo, x=df$sample)
```

The way of calculation is similar to [Calculating cumulative standard deviation by group using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874582/calculating-cumulative-standard-deviation-by-group-using-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

result:

```
#> sapply(seq(nrow(df)), foo, x=df$sample)
# [1]         NA 0.23975006 0.12629071 0.45777934 0.84662051 0.83168998 0.11925118 0.50873996 0.06607348 0.63103339You can put the result in your dataframe:

df$result <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), foo, x=df$sample)
```

Here is a compact version of the calculation (from @lmo)

```
c(NA, sapply(2:10, function(i) tail(pnorm(df$sample[1:i], mean(df$sample[1:i]), sd(df$sample[1:i])), 1)))
```

Comment: Or just smash it all together like `c(NA, sapply(2:10, function(i) tail(pnorm(df$sample[1:i], mean(df$sample[1:i]), sd(df$sample[1:i])), 1)))`.