# Mathematical function (for e.g., sd) of all prior values of a variable, by group

Tags: r, data.table

MWE.

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(
    g=rep(c("x", "y"), each=4), # grouping variable
    time=c(1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8),    # time index
    val=1:8)                    # value

setkeyv(x, c("g", "time"))

cumsd <- function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x)-1, head, x=x), sd)

x[, cumsd(val), by=g]

## Output
#    g        V1
# 1: x        NA
# 2: x        NA
# 3: x 0.7071068
# 4: x 1.0000000
# 5: y        NA
# 6: y        NA
# 7: y 0.7071068
# 8: y 1.0000000
```

I want to compute the standard deviation (or more generally, a mathematical function) of all prior values (not including the current value), per observation, by group, in R.

The `cumsd` ("cumulative sd") function above does what I need. For e.g. row 3, `V1 = sd(c(1, 2))`, corresponding to the values in rows 1 and 2. Row 7, `V1 = sd(c(5, 6))`, corresponding to the values in rows 5 and 6.

However, `cumsd` is very slow (too slow to use in my real-world application). Any ideas on how to do the computation more efficiently?

**Edit**

For sd we can use runSD from library TTR as discussed here: [Calculating cumulative standard deviation by group using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874582/calculating-cumulative-standard-deviation-by-group-using-r)

Gabor's answer below addresses the more general case of any arbitrary mathematical function on prior values. Though potentially the generalisability comes at some cost of efficiency.

Comment: You should be able to write a more efficient cumulative variance function and then transform variance to standard deviation. This is because it is easier to update sums than an expression where the sum is under a square root. Alternatively, I'd be surprised if this functionality isn't already in some package -- perhaps `zoo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating cumulative standard deviation by group using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874582/calculating-cumulative-standard-deviation-by-group-using-r)

Comment: That question uses the current value whereas this one does not. Also this question was looking not just for sd but for a general function so an answer only working for sd does not seem to fulfill this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the window widths as a vector and then omit the last value in the window for each application of `sd`.

```
library(zoo)

x[, sd:=rollapplyr(val, seq_along(val), function(x) sd(head(x, -1)), fill = NA), by = g]
```

giving:

```
> x
   g time val        sd
1: x    1   1        NA
2: x    3   2        NA
3: x    5   3 0.7071068
4: x    7   4 1.0000000
5: y    2   5        NA
6: y    4   6        NA
7: y    6   7 0.7071068
8: y    8   8 1.0000000
```

Alternately we can specify the offsets in a list.  Negative offsets, used here, refer to prior values so -1 is the immediate prior value, -2 is the value before that and so on.

```
negseq <- function(x) -seq_len(x))
x[, sd:=rollapplyr(val, lapply(seq_along(val)-1, negseq), sd, fill = NA), by = g]
```

giving:

```
> x
   g time val        sd
1: x    1   1        NA
2: x    3   2        NA
3: x    5   3 0.7071068
4: x    7   4 1.0000000
5: y    2   5        NA
6: y    4   6        NA
7: y    6   7 0.7071068
8: y    8   8 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `TTR::runSD` with `shift`:

```
library(TTR);
setDT(x)[, cum_sd := shift(runSD(val, n = 2, cumulative = TRUE)) , g]
#    g time val    cum_sd
#1: x    1   1        NA
#2: x    3   2        NA
#3: x    5   3 0.7071068
#4: x    7   4 1.0000000
#5: y    2   5        NA
#6: y    4   6        NA
#7: y    6   7 0.7071068
#8: y    8   8 1.0000000
```

Comment: This works perfectly for standard deviation, thanks! Gabor's answer has the advantage that it works with any function and is in that sense more general, though I would imagine this approach is more efficient.

Comment: @AnirbanMukherjee Agreed. Do take a look at `TTR` though; it offers a lot of cumulative functions (`max`,`min`, `median`, `cor`, `var`, etc.); it would be interesting to run a benchmark comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that neither option were fast enough for my application (millions of groups and observations). But your comments inspired me to write a small function in Rcpp that did the trick. Thanks everyone!

```
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)
x <- data.table(
    g=rep(c("x", "y"), each=4), # grouping variable
    time=c(1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8),    # time index
    val=1:8)                    # value
setkeyv(x, c("g", "time"))

cumsd <- function(x) sapply(sapply(seq_along(x)-1, head, x=x), sd)
x[, v1:=cumsd(val), by=g]

cppFunction('
Rcpp::NumericVector rcpp_cumsd(Rcpp::NumericVector inputVector){
    int len = inputVector.size();
    Rcpp::NumericVector outputVector(len, NumericVector::get_na());
    if (len < 3) return (outputVector);
    for (int i = 2; i < len; ++i){
        outputVector(i) = Rcpp::sd(inputVector[Rcpp::seq(0, i - 1)]);
        }
    return(outputVector);
};
')
x[, v2:= rcpp_cumsd(val), by=g]

all.equal(x$v1, x$v2)
## TRUE
```

The speed difference seems to depend on the number of groups vs. the number of observations per group in the data.table. I won't post benchmarks but in my case, the Rcpp version was much, much faster.